# GWT + ReastEasy - Cookie not returning to server

Tags: json, rest, gwt, resteasy, resty-gwt

I'm working on GWT application which has REST backend. Also I'm using RESTEasy and RestyGWT library.

Now I've created permanent cookie on server side and it's been returned to client(I can see it's stored in browser cookie list) but when I make new REST call cookie is not send to server. I've checked with firebug.
However JSESSIONID is sent both ways with no problem. I've assumed that this is done implicitly, but is there something extra I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are handled by the browser. With RestGWT you are sending Ajax requests from your javascript application code. So if you need to pass the value of your cookie to your ajax request you need to retrieve it first then add it manually to your RestGWT request by using a Dispatcher for example.

To retrieve the cookie value value can use `com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies`

Then to add you cookie value to your RestyGWT query you can use a Dispatcher `org.fusesource.restygwt.client.Dispatcher`